# Kubuntu 22.04 TLS: printer difficulties

Tags: printing, kde

I go through this every time I repave the hard drive (re-install the OS): choosing which connection method and which driver to use. What's going on here with this list of drivers, with apparent duplicates?[image]

Comment: "repave the hard drive"? Could you [edit] your Question and translate that to english?